# (ionSelect) not invoking on ion-select-option

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to get the **index value** of the selected `item` from dropdown.

In order to do that, this is the code I am trying:

```
  <ion-select  okText="Okay" cancelText="Dismiss" [(ngModel)]="dropdown1" (ionChange)="onSelectChange($event)" >
    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let list of goalList;let i=index;" (ionSelect)=" myfun(); myIndex = i" value="{{list.docid}}">
      {{list.personalEmail}}
    </ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
```

I was never getting `myIndex` number, so I tested by adding a `function`. The function is never invoked.

I searched and found this solution but it was working on `ion-option` for **Ionic 3**, but this is not working on `ion-select-option` in **Ionic 4**.

Comment: for interest sake, why do you need the index value? Perhaps there is another approach the the problem which will solve the issue

Comment: i have got the value using the array and value, initially i was thinking one way :)

Comment: glad you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to set the `ion-select-option` value as an object as below with the docid and index, this way the object with the docid and index will bind to the ngModel and will be accessible on the `ionChange` event.detail.value

```
<ion-select okText="Okay" cancelText="Dismiss" [(ngModel)]="dropdown1" (ionChange)="onSelectChange($event)">
    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let list of goalList;let i=index;" [value]="{docid:list.docid,index:i}">
      {{list.personalEmail}}
    </ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```